# How to open browser from Visual Studio Code API

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am just exploring a way in order to open the default browser from Visual Studio Code API used for developing extensions.

Following is my code :

```
var disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('extension.browser', () => {
  // The code you place here will be executed every time your command is executed
  vscode.Uri.call("http://facebook.com");
});
```

How to open Browser URL from API using vscode class.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There is no need for node or external libraries.

If you are using VS Code 1.31+, use the `vscode.env.openExternal` function:

```
import * as vscode from 'vscode';

vscode.env.openExternal(vscode.Uri.parse('https://example.com'));
```

For older VS Code versions, use the `vscode.open` command:

```
vscode.commands.executeCommand('vscode.open', vscode.Uri.parse('https://example.com'))
```

Both of these will open the page in the user's default browser

Comment: Is it possible to get a callback when the browser is closed? Doesn't seem like it.

Comment: @MichaelFlanakin Not with `vscode.open`. You'd need to write a vscode extension that uses node's `child_process` or similar if you need to do that

Comment: @ShanKhan No. You'd need to write a vscode extension to do that. Take a look at the [`vscode.previewHtml` command](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api-commands) for this (for example, use an iframe inside an html preview to load the page)

Comment: It's seems that `vscode.env.open` was renamed to `vscode.env.openExternal`.

Comment: is there a way to open email address in default mail client?

Comment: Use try using a mailto uri: `mailto:someone@example.com`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to install an external dependency. Opening an URL can be simply done with **just** the Node.js libraries and system commands. For e.g. use the [child_process.exec](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) to open an URL.

Declare a function like so:

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;

function openURL(url) {
  let opener;

  switch (process.platform) {
    case 'darwin':
      opener = 'open';
      break;
    case 'win32':
      opener = 'start';
      break;
    default:
      opener = 'xdg-open';
      break;
  }

  return exec(`${opener} "${url.replace(/"/g, '\\\"')}"`);
}
```

and then call it from your code

```
openURL('http://stackoverflow.com');
```

Comment: With Windows 10 I had to add "" (two empty quotes) after the opener for it to work. This is a good solution when you run into VSCode's double encoding bug for certain urls.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use npm open url in order to open in browser.

```
var openurl = require('openurl').open;
    openurl("http://google.com");
```